# Why does a control volume distort over time if the flow velocity along it's edges is not constant?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Part of my fluid dynamics notes covers the Navier-Stokes equations and their derivation, and I guess I don't really understand control volumes very well.

To my understading, a control volume is essentially an imaginary region of space that we define for the sake of analysis of the fluid flowing through/with that volume. The notes describes a situation in which an infinitecimally small CV, initially square in shape, translates and deforms after a small increment in time, in a manner similar to the picture.

[image: CV deformation]

The translation implies a Langrangian-refernece frame (to me at least), and the skew is attributed to the fact the velocity at the bottom-left (reference) corner is different to the upper-left and bottom-right corners. If the CV were some physical object made of rigid beams and loose joints, then intuitively I guesss the object would behave as such. But to my understanding, a CV does not enclose a specified amount of mass or element of fluid, rather matter may flow freely through it.

The question then, is why will a CV distort over time if the flow velocity along it's edges is not constant? What does this represent?

My apologies if this question isn't formed very well. I didn't pay too much attention to fluids last year, and that probably shows. Cheers

Comment: Control Volume is a general term and can mean different things in different calculations (rigid, moving etc.). From your diagram it looks like you're dealing with a moving (and deforming) CV that encloses a fixed volume of fluid. The velocities are probably the velocities of the boundaries, not the velocities of the fluid crossing the boundaries.

Comment: A Lagrangian control volume does contain a specific amount of mass.  Lagrangian means that we are tracking the motion of the individual mass particles.